# Arclength parametrisation in 4D.

Tags: curves, classical-mechanics, arc-length

My question is to do with parametrisation of arclengths.

As part of a course on mechanics (with mathematical focus), I have covered intrinsic coordinates in a plane curve. In class and homeworks etc, we covered ideas such as determining the shape of a chain hanging under its own weight.

We also learned arclength parametrisation. in three dimensions (although it loses the use of $\psi$ and instead parametrises in terms of arclength only using the i,j,k basis vectors), and its application to something like a helix for example.

I have a question that sprung to mind however: Could we extend this idea of parametrising a curve in terms of its arclength be extended to a 4 dimensional analogue or higher, so we let:

$(\frac{dw}{ds})^2+(\frac{dx}{ds})^2+(\frac{dy}{ds})^2+(\frac{dz}{ds})^2$=1

And attempt to parametrise from there?

Does this still "make sense"? Or is there an issue with it?

If so, what would be a good example of something in 4D space which isn't just a straight line for example that could be parametrised in terms of its arclength? Preferably something written in parametric form (i.e w($\phi$)=... x($\phi$)=...y($\phi$)=... z($\phi$)=...) AND a parametrisation in terms of arclength so I can try to observe the behaviour a little better!

Comment: Sorry to the person who suggested an edit: I just changed some of the post so it makes sense, so I don't want to revert it back to where the meaning is lost.

Comment: "Yes," a smooth path in a Euclidean space of arbitrary dimension has an arclength function, and if the path is regular (has non-vanishing velocity) it admits an arclength parametrization. <> Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, that was half of my question. The other half was an example of something in 4D which can be parametrised in terms of its arclength that isn't something completely trivial ( like if I set the w component to always be zero). Something that wouldn't be too difficult to derive  , like is there , for example , an equivalent to the helix in 4D which might be interesting perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both the measurement of arclenght and the reparameterization by arclength are well-defined in $n$ dimensions, where $n$ coul be $4$, as in your question, or much larger.

As an example, the set of points $(x, y, z, w)$ satisfying the relations
$$
x^2 + y^2 = 1 \\
z^2 + w^2 = 1
$$
constitute something called "the flat torus". A typical path on that surface is something like
$$
\gamma(t) = (t, \sqrt{1-t^2},t, \sqrt{1-t^2})
$$
whose tangent vector is ... um ...
$$
\gamma'(t) = (1, \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}},1, \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}})
$$
whose squared length is
$$
1^2 + \frac{t^2}{1-t^2} + 1^2 + \frac{t^2}{1-t^2}
$$
which is certainly not $1$, so this curve is not parameterized by arclength.
(It's also only defined for $-1 \le t \le 1$.)

We can find a different path that traverses the same points, but *does* have constant speed, namely
$$
\mu(s)= (\sin(s/2), \cos(s/2), \sin(s/2), \cos(s/2))
$$
where in this case $s$ ranges from $-\pi$ to $0$. I'll let you check that the length of $\mu'(s)$ is in fact $1$ everywhere. To see that $\mu$ is a reparameterization of $\gamma$, consider that
$$
\mu(s) = \gamma(\sin(s/2))
$$

In general, reparameterizing exactly is very difficult -- the integral you have to compute is often messy, and inverting the resulting function is messier. I built this example so that it happened to be obvious, because I've played with the flat torus in the past. The *proof* that a reparameterization exists is exactly the same in $n$ dimensions as it is in 2D: for a non-stopping curve (i.e., one whose tangent always has nonzero length), you show that integrating the length of the tangent from some starting point, i.e., computing
$$
L(t) = \int_{t_0}^t \| \gamma'(s) \| ds
$$
gives you an **increasing** function $L$; that means that $L$ must have an inverse ... call it $H$. And then defining
$$
\mu(s) = \gamma(H(s))
$$
gives you a function which, by the chain rule and fundamental theorem of calculus, has unit-length tangent everywhere, and traverses the same point as does $\gamma$. The only problem is that you can seldom write down the formula for $H$, or for $\mu$, so all you know is that in the abstract, some such thing exists.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was looking for. I have just one question, is it not $\mu(s)= \gamma(sin(s/2))$, or am I reading that incorrectly?

Comment: You're correct. I've edited, and added a little more info.